Get Azure VM (windows 10) user login and Logout information using PowerShell
new to PowerShell can you please help me get logon and Logout user information of azure VM.
problem is account name is showing as empty when i checked in event log i can see Account Name.
tried to check with UserId but no luck. using following for reference.
need to get account Name (person logged in to VM) with Logon and logoff time
running this script on VM for now but end requirement is to collect info of VM using PowerShell from laptop
# Define the time range for the query
$startTime = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)  # Last 7 days
$endTime = Get-Date

# Get logon events (Event ID 4624)
$logonEvents = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
    LogName = 'Security'
    Id = 4624
    StartTime = $startTime
    EndTime = $endTime
}

# Get logoff events (Event ID 4634)
$logoffEvents = Get-WinEvent -FilterHashtable @{
    LogName = 'Security'
    Id = 4634
    StartTime = $startTime
    EndTime = $endTime
}

# Create a custom object to store the results
$results = @()

# Process logon events
foreach ($logonEvent in $logonEvents) {
    $accountName = ($logonEvent.Properties | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 5}).Value
    $logonTime = $logonEvent.TimeCreated

    # Find the corresponding logoff event
    $logoffEvent = $logoffEvents | Where-Object {
        ($_.Properties | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 5}).Value -eq $accountName -and
        $_.TimeCreated -gt $logonTime
    } | Select-Object -First 1

    $logoffTime = $logoffEvent.TimeCreated

    # Add the result to the array
    $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
        AccountName = $accountName
        UserLogonTime = $logonTime
        UserLogoffTime = $logoffTime
    }
}

# Display the results as a table
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize


Do you want to retrieve user login and logout information from another laptop, including the username and the time details?

The property objects in the Properties collection only has one member property each - the Value property - they don't have an Id property, so:
$accountName = ($logonEvent.Properties | Where-Object {$_.Id -eq 5}).Value

... will not work.
To select a value by index use either an index access operation, or Select-Object -Index:
$accountName = $logonEvent.Properties[5].Value
# or 
$accountName = ($logonEvent.Properties | Select-Object -Index 5).Value


Update the Account name as suggested but now am not getting logoff time, only login time
